# How to use COM in dotnet without registering

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, com

I have a COM dll that communicates to biometric machine, but registration is required to use in dot net project, please guide me can I embed or merge into the project in a way that no need to register that dll on hosting server.

Comment: What have you tried? Helping can only be done once you've done something. The term is "reg-free" or "registration-free" COM. Here is a starting point "Registration-Free COM Interop": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/registration-free-com-interop

Comment: I need some kind of basic tutorial to learn and implement, although no idea about dll, I had read reg-free com but didn't find implementation code to get understand i.e sample code
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-build-registration-free-com-components?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 1):

Do you know if this is a .net .dll and assembly?

While it could be created and used as a com object?
And perhaps this COM object was written for use by say office or VB6 (unmanged windows code systems)?

That .dll STILL might have been written in .net.

If that is the case, then you don't need to use say CreateObject, and you don't actually need to use com-interop to use that object.

I write + create + build COM objects for Office/Access, and other windows sfotware all the time in .net.

But, if you lucky, you can take the COM object dll's and JUST reference that .net assembly from your project and you off to the races so to speak.

It only takes about 15 seconds to test/try doing this. So, have you attempted to referance the .dll from your current project? (do try!!!).

Of course, if vs tells you that it not a valid .net assembly, then it is a COM object written say in c++ or even VB6, and thus is un-managed code.

In that case, then yes, you have to use com inter-op.

I use COM free registering from VBA, and un-managed code systems all the time. (the reason of course is deployment headaches). But, in these cases, I doing the COM free registration from the un-managed code system (VB6, VBA, office code).

Strangly, I not done the reverse!!! (which is what you looking to do!!!).

Now, it is certainly assumed that this COM object is NOT a ActiveX version, since that does require registering, or at least its very difficult without doing so.

so there are several types of COM objects, and while the term:

```
  ActiveX
  OLE
  COM
```

The above really all often quite much means the same thing - the COM object interface is used for all of the above. But, ActiveX has a bit more extensions, since that tends to mean some kind of custom control, and NOT just say some library code you need to consume.

Next? Are you 100% sure this is a COM object, or is it a simple un-managed .dll?

You can certainly call + use + consume unmanaged .dll library code from .net.

(you need to force your project from ANY CPU to x86 (32 bits), or x64 (64 bits - but COM objects written to x64 are not all that common these days).

So, do you as a general rule have to use

regsvr32.exe - this is to register the COM object (unmanaged)

regasm.exe  - this is the .net one - it creates a compatible COM object out of managed code objects. If you are having to use this command to register, then you are in VERY good fortune and luck - since that means this is managed (.net code), and you actaully don't need to register the .net object WHEN writing and using .net code!!!! (you only need that registering for non .net systems).

So, how is (was) that COM object to be registered in the past?